# How can I store a game map and display a portion of it on the screen?

Tags: c++, graphics

Hey.
I'm going to write a simple ship shooting game as CG homework, so I'm planning to use some map system (though there's no need for that, it'll be an "extra") and I have no clue about how to represent a map and show it 'in parts', I mean, not all map will be visible in a single frame.
How do people usually work with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a [QuadTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). It breaks your map down into small components based by area. It lets you define how much space you want to see, which makes it ideal for zooming in and out, or panning around.

There's a [C# implementation](http://digitseven.com/QuadTree.aspx) you could probably adapt to be C++ fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use tiles and a fixed size 2D array of pointers to tiles. The pointers are so you can reuse tiles in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do it like how early video game hardware did: store a 2D array of bytes, where each byte is the index of an 8x8 pixel "tile". Elsewhere store an array of 8x8 pixel tiles. Also store the offset in pixels from the upper-left corner of the map to the upper-left corner of the screen.

When it is time to draw the map, render only the tiles that should be visible on the screen, according to the offset in pixels from the map corner to the screen corner:

```
 int tile_x = pixel_x / tile_width;
 int tile_y = pixel_y / tile_height;
 for( int y=tile_y; y<=tile_y+screen_height_in_tiles; ++y )
 {
   for( int x=tile_x; x<=tile_x+screen_width_in_tiles; ++x )
   {
     int screen_x = tile_x * tile_width - ( pixel_x % tile_width );
     int screen_y = tile_y * tile_height - ( pixel_y % tile_height );
     render_tile( screen_x, screen_y, map[y][x] );
   }
 }
```

This code is not optimally fast, and some logic is missing, such as how to deal with a map that is partially scrolled off the screen. But it's a start.